# Not able to parse JSON array string

Tags: javascript, json

I am working on project in which I am sending request ot server for getting JSON array string. I am using following java code to create one JSON array list string.

```
JSONArray itemList = new JSONArray();
for(int i =0; i<4; i++) {
    String exe = "m";
    final JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();
    jsonObj.put("filePath", 30);
    jsonObj.put("duration", 12222);
    jsonObj.put("bitRate", 1111);
    jsonObj.put("widht", 12);
    jsonObj.put("format", 123);
    jsonObj.put("height", 12);
    jsonObj.put("exe", exe);
    JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject();

    try {
        itemList.put(jsonObj);
        // jObject.put("itemList", itemList);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("ERROR");
    }
}
return itemList.toString();
```

On client side, in AJAX response, I am getting following String by using above method:

```
[{"duration":12222&sbquo;"height":12&sbquo;"widht":12&sbquo;"filePath":30&sbquo;"format":123&sbquo;"bitRate":1111&sbquo;"exe":"m"}&sbquo;{"duration":12222&sbquo;"height":12&sbquo;"widht":12&sbquo;"filePath":30&sbquo;"format":123&sbquo;"bitRate":1111&sbquo;"exe":"m"}&sbquo;{"duration":12222&sbquo;"height":12&sbquo;"widht":12&sbquo;"filePath":30&sbquo;"format":123&sbquo;"bitRate":1111&sbquo;"exe":"m"}&sbquo;{"duration":12222&sbquo;"height":12&sbquo;"widht":12&sbquo;"filePath":30&sbquo;"format":123&sbquo;"bitRate":1111&sbquo;"exe":"m"}]
```

When I am using JQuery to parse it as follows:

```
$jQ.each($jQ.parseJSON(responseJSON), function(idx, obj) {
    alert(obj.filePath);
});
```

I am getting JS error as `JSON.parse: expected property name or '}'`

I am not getting why this error is occuring.

Comment: In deed there is a mistake in your JSON, paste your JSON here-> http://jsonlint.com/

You will see why

Comment: you are getting JSON it is javascript obj ... you did not need to parse it i think

Comment: Your JSON is not valid  ...

Answer (score 1):

According to jsonlint.com, you should put values into `""`.

Because of the special character `&`

Answer (score 1):

Just looking at the first few lines:

`[{"duration":12222&sbquo;"height":12&sbquo;`

This doesn't appear to be valid json. `duration` is the key and the value is `12222` which is `Integer`, however you also have string data `&sbquo;` next to the int, which makes this invalid json data.

If you have mixed data, encapsulate it with double quote to treat it as a string.

---

**Update**

`,` is html encoded to `&sbquo;` - there's your problem.

Try this json string:

```
[
    {
        "duration": 12222,
        "height": 12,
        "widht": 12,
        "filePath": 30,
        "format": 123,
        "bitRate": 1111,
        "exe": "m"
    },
    {
        "duration": 12222,
        "height": 12,
        "widht": 12,
        "filePath": 30,
        "format": 123,
        "bitRate": 1111,
        "exe": "m"
    },
    {
        "duration": 12222,
        "height": 12,
        "widht": 12,
        "filePath": 30,
        "format": 123,
        "bitRate": 1111,
        "exe": "m"
    },
    {
        "duration": 12222,
        "height": 12,
        "widht": 12,
        "filePath": 30,
        "format": 123,
        "bitRate": 1111,
        "exe": "m"
    }
]
```

this now validates.

Comment: Do you have a source for that html-encoding? The online tools that I found don't HTML encode comma to &sbquo; and if they did encide it at all it should be &#44;

Comment: http://www.w3.org/wiki/Common_HTML_entities_used_for_typography (Single low quote) - perhaps he's wrong the wrong comma?

Answer (score 0):

Your java environment may be serializing the array incorrectly.

Instead of ‚ - single bottom quote U+201A - you should have a comma (, U+002C).